# Only take most recent line from CSV when a value appears twice

Tags: java, csv, duplicates, mule, dataweave

I'm working with a CSV file in Mule that could look something like the following:

```
ID|LastUpdated
01|01/12/2016 09:00:00
01|01/12/2016 09:45:00
02|01/12/2016 09:00:00
02|01/12/2016 09:45:00
03|01/12/2016 09:00:00
```

I'm trying to find a way of stripping out all duplicate occurrences of an `ID` value by taking only the most recent one, determined by the `LastUpdated` column. I'm trying to achieve this using DataWeave but have so far had no luck. I'm open to writing the logic in to a custom Java class but have limited knowledge of how to do that as well.

My desired output is something like the following:

```
ID|LastUpdated
01|01/12/2016 09:45:00
02|01/12/2016 09:45:00
03|01/12/2016 09:00:00
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

**Edit**: it's worth noting that I expect the inbound file to be quite large (up to 000's of rows) so I need to be aware of performance in my solution

**Edit**: a solution using DataWeave can be found on the Mulesoft forum [here](http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/40897/only-take-most-recent-line-from-csv-when-a-value-a.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw this one and I believe @danw had asked this question on Mule forum too. There is a better way to achieve it with DataWeave. 
Check out my answer on mule forum - 
http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/40897/only-take-most-recent-line-from-csv-when-a-value-a.html#answer-40975

Answer (score 3):

If the dates/hours are always sorted into your CSV like in the example you gave the you can keep a reference on all your ID as keys into a Map and just update the value corresponding to the ids:

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    // I replace all the CSV reading by this list for the example
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    lines.add("01|01/12/2016 09:00:00");
    lines.add("01|01/12/2016 09:45:00");
    lines.add("02|01/12/2016 09:00:00");
    lines.add("02|01/12/2016 09:45:00");
    lines.add("03|01/12/2016 09:00:00");
    Iterator it = lines.iterator();
    
    Map<String, String> lastLines = new HashMap<String, String>();
    while (it.hasNext()) { // Iterator on the CVS lines here
        String s = (String)it.next();
        String id = s.substring(0,  s.indexOf("|"));
        String val = s.substring(s.indexOf("|") + 1 , s.length());
        lastLines.put(id, val);
    }
    Iterator<String> keys = lastLines.keySet().iterator();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String id = (String) keys.next();
        System.out.println(id + "|" + lastLines.get(id));
    }
}
```

This produce :

> 01|01/12/2016 09:45:00
>
> 02|01/12/2016 09:45:00
>
> 03|01/12/2016 09:00:00

If the CSV records can be in any order then you need to add a validation of the dates to keep only the most recent for each id.

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

public static void main(String... args) {
    // I replace all the CSV reading by this list for the example
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    
    lines.add("01|01/12/2016 09:45:00");
    lines.add("01|01/12/2016 09:00:00");
    lines.add("02|01/12/2016 09:00:00");
    lines.add("02|01/12/2016 09:45:00");
    lines.add("03|01/12/2016 09:00:00");
    Iterator it = lines.iterator();

    Map<String, String> lastLines = new HashMap<String, String>();
    while (it.hasNext()) { // Iterator on the CVS lines here
        String s = (String)it.next();
        String id = s.substring(0,  s.indexOf("|"));
        String val = s.substring(s.indexOf("|") + 1 , s.length());
        if(lastLines.containsKey(id)){
            try{
                Date storeDate = sdf.parse(lastLines.get(id));
                Date readDate = sdf.parse(val);
                if(readDate.getTime() > storeDate.getTime())
                    lastLines.put(id, val);
            }catch(ParseException pe){
                pe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            lastLines.put(id, val);
        }
    }
    Iterator<String> keys = lastLines.keySet().iterator();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String id = (String) keys.next();
        System.out.println(id + "|" + lastLines.get(id));
    }

}
```

I'm not sure about the date format you are currently using. You may need to change the format of the parser`"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`. You can find the related documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. When you say "If the dates/hours are always sorted into your CSV like in the example", do you mean in order? If that's the case, then no. The records could be in any order.

Comment: See my updated answer taking in account the records in any order.

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume, how performant do you think this will be if working with 000's lines? I don't have a detailed enough understanding of the language to know

Comment: I just made a small test on my machine with 8000 rows, took around 80/90ms.

Comment: Thank you! I will adapt the answer to work within a Mule flow and update my post accordingly. Appreciate your help.